# Match and replace string unless preceded by another specific string

Tags: regex, perl

I am using Perl and need to have a regular expression that will match a string if it contains a specific person's name, for example, "Carol Bean", unless the person has a title(Mr. Mrs. Ms. Miss), and without using negative look behind.

For example:

`Carol Bean is nice` would have a match for just `Carol Bean` but, `Miss Carol Bean is nice` would have no matches.

The end goal is to replace the match with `the student, Carol Bean`, as such:

`Carol Bean is nice.` would become: `the student Carol Bean is nice.`, but
`Miss Carol Bean is nice.` would remain unchanged, and `Miss Carol Bean and Carol Bean.` would become, `Miss Carol Bean and the student, Carol Bean.`

How do you create such a regular expression without using negative look behind?

Comment: `without using negative look behind ?` Any specific reason for this constraint? `perl` does support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following will be helpful (although it doesn't insert commas):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } qw/Mr. Mrs. Ms. Miss/;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/(\S*)\s*\K(Carol Bean)/$hash{$1} ? $2 : ($1 ? 't' : 'T') . "he student $2"/ge;
    print;
}

__DATA__
Carol Bean is nice.
Miss Carol Bean is nice.
Miss Carol Bean and Carol Bean.
Carol Bean is not Mrs. Carol Bean.
```

Output:

```
The student Carol Bean is nice.
Miss Carol Bean is nice.
Miss Carol Bean and the student Carol Bean.
The student Carol Bean is not Mrs. Carol Bean.
```

Comment: Why didn't you put the comma?

Comment: @justhalf - It would take more than just a regex to determine whether adding a comma to "the student" produces a well-formed sentence.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was some technical difficulties, apparently it's language issue. =)

Comment: @justhalf - You're exactly right.  Perhaps I should have mentioned that in my original message to the OP.